# Unable to determine the serialization information for "linq query"

Tags: c#, mongodb, azure-cosmosdb

"fullNames" is a list of strings that I want to search for in a database with the 2 tables "FistName" and "LastName". But this code returns the error: "Unable to determine the serialization information for u => (u.FirstName + u.LastName)."

```
var filter = builder.In(u => u.FirstName + u.LastName, fullNames);

var task = _db.GetCollection<Models.User>(Models.CosmosDb.Collections.Users)
                            .Find(filter)
                            .ToListAsync();

var users = await _asyncRetryPolicy.ExecuteAsync(() => task);
```

Tried to replace the first line with this, but with the same result:

```
var filter = builder.In(u => $"{u.FirstName}{u.LastName}", fullNames);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The driver expects a lambda expression that evaluates to a simple property as parameter for `In`. In the sample, the lambda expression concatenates two properties, hence the error.

Instead of using a `Find`, you could use `Aggregate`. This offers more options when querying and reshaping the data.

In this sample, the first stage would be a `$set` stage that concatenates the first and last name of the document. In a subsequent `$match` stage, you can include the `$in` condition and filter the data.

From a performance perspective, it would be best if you store the full name with the documents. Then you only need a simple filter that can also use an index.